# ORA-01722: Invalid number when execute query

Tags: oracle

I am seeking some help to resolve an issue with Oracle SQL query. I am trying to find the difference between two columns. Here is the query format

```
((TO_CHAR (TRUNC (SYSDATE) + 
           numtodsinterval(DECODE(
          LAG(e.actualdeparttime, 1, 0) OVER (Partition by es.evstrname ORDER BY e.actualdeparttime),1,0, 
          (LAG(e.actualdeparttime, 1, 0) OVER (Partition by es.evstrname ORDER BY e.actualdeparttime))),'second'),'hh24:mi')) 
        - (TO_CHAR (TRUNC (SYSDATE) + numtodsinterval(DECODE( e.actualarrivetime, -1, 0,  e.actualarrivetime),   'second'),'hh24:mi'))) as time_taken
```

Query shows and error. Please help. Thanks

GG

Comment: split your query in small pieces so would be easy found where is the error.

Comment: You appear to be trying to subtract two strings, representing times in HH24:MI format, from each other. If you're starting with the times in seconds, why aren't you just subtracting those directly?

Comment: Thanks Alex for the reply. I have time in seconds in the database. I need to convert it into time format and that is why I used HH24:MI format. What do you recommend? I can subtract in seconds but the output I require in time format. Thanks again.

Comment: Do the maths then format the result